# Xamarin Android TimePicker how to change underline color using Styles

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

[image]

Currently the under line color is White, how would I change the color.

I've looked at this solution using style which I really like, but which property do I need to set to update this under line color?
[Xamarin Android - Change colors for TimePicker keyboard view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643871/xamarin-android-change-colors-for-timepicker-keyboard-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a property in style may affect the appearance of more than one control.

For example in your issue,you could try to define in your style to change the underline color like:

```
<style name="Theme.picker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
  <item name="colorControlNormal">#ff00ff</item> // the underline normal color which no focus
  <item name="colorControlActivated">#ff0000</item>// the underline activate color which focus
</style>
```

[image]