# Change Text Color for Xamarin TimePicker

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I change the color of the text circled in the below screenshot?
I played around with the **style.xml** but have not yet found any property that impacts this parts.
[image: TimePicker]

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643871/xamarin-android-change-colors-for-timepicker-keyboard-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code into `style.xml` in android project.

1. Create a new style which defines the color on Timepicker.

   ```
   <style name="Theme.picker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        //background color
        <item name="android:background">#13216a</item>
        //Title background color
        <item name="colorAccent">#f8a519</item>
        //text color
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
         //number text color
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FF66FF</item>        
   </style>
   ```
2. Apply the style in `MainTheme` .

   ```
   <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/Theme.picker</item>
   ```

##### Screen shot

[image: Before] [image: After]

###### Notice: This is a simple solution, and it will also change the button text color, if you want to separate them, you will need a custom renderer.